# Swift 4.2 Decoding Object Unknown Keys

Tags: ios, json, rest, swift4, decodable

I'm currently building an application as a personal project that relies on fetching data from a server. I can successfully fetch the data however facing trouble when trying to decode. The problem I'm facing is that I don't know the keys for some of the objects until I receive them from the server. The data that I get back looks like this:

```
{
    "result": 0,
    "id": 1,
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "UNKOWN_KEY": {
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
        },
        "UNKOWN_KEY": {
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
        },
        "UNKOWN_KEY": {
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
        },
        "UNKOWN_KEY": {
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
            "knownKey": "test",
        }
    }
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how to decode those `UNKOWN_KEY`s and it's stopping me from progressing. I've tried using the following:

```
let dynamicContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DeviceDataKey.self)

for key in dynamicContainer.allKeys {
    if let deviceData = try? dynamicContainer.decode(ACDeviceData.self, forKey: key) {
        data.insert(deviceData, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Any help that anyone can offer will be super appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your value for `"data"` is dictionary with key of type `String` and value as your custom model. If you're using `Codable`, just specify type of `data` as dictionary

```
let data: [String: YourModel]
```

---

Then decode received `Data` as your `Response` model

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let result, id: Int
    let error: String?
    let data: [String: YourModel]
}

struct YourModel: Decodable {
    let knownKey: String
}
```

---

If you need to get all your models, just use `compactMap` on your dictionary

```
do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let models = decoded.data.compactMap { $0.value }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Mate. You're a legend. Thank you so much, you've made my night!